# Matlab Xcorr function returns NaNs for a large block of the return array

Tags: matlab, signals, cross-correlation

I have some synthetic signal data to cross correlate before moving on with real data but the xcorr function is returning an odd result.

I have added a delay onto either the start (delay =100) or end of the respective data sets which are the same size (2101 x 1 double) and put them through xcorr which has returned an array (4201 x 1 double).

The result has NaNs between rows 101 and 2205 and then a ring down effect after that start at an order of x10^5. I have now attached pictures of the result[image: Cross correlation result]

Can anyone please offer some suggestions on how to correct what I am attempting to do? I am expecting to be able to plot the result and see a spike at the delay that I have set.

Thanks

EDIT:

Short example code

```
    X = [-4.99 -0.298 4.95 12.06 15.76 18.86 19.00 17.82 14.35 11.77 6.71 0.80 -5.07 -11.79 -15.34 -18.60 -18.56 -19.31 -14.37 -11.51 -5.04];
    Y = [14.13 18.48 7.53 -3.41 -8.41 -13.40 -15.37 -17.34 -16.83 -16.33 -12.21 -8.09 -8.80 -9.52 3.90 17.31 17.52 17.72 17.73 17.75 16.90];

    N = length(X);
    delay = 2;

    % set up two new arrays which will have random noise at ends 
    Xx = zeros(N+delay,1);
    Yx = zeros(N+delay,1);

    for i=1:N+delay
        if i<=delay
            Xx(i) = rand;
        elseif i>delay
            Xx(i) = X(i-delay);
        end
    end

    for i=1:N+delay
        if i<=N
            Yx(i) = Y(i);
        elseif i>N
            Yx(i) = rand;
        end
    end

    C = xcorr(Xx,Yx);
```

Comment: Please include an example with some small vector that reproduces the problem, so we can run the code

Comment: Question now edited with code

Comment: Your example code produces a result without NaN's, and a picture without ringing. So what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Well really if I knew I wouldn't have to ask!

Comment: I mean, what is wrong with the _result_ of that code. You say there are `NaN`'s and ringing, but your code doesn't produce `NaN'`s  or ringing. So what is your question exactly?